# Getting "Request timed out." every 5-10 pings when I ping the wired router

Tags: ping

Recently, I'm having random lags/delays/packet loss so I went to speedtest.net to check my speed. My speed result is good, like my normal internet speed which is around 90mbps. So the next thing I did is to ping google and that's where I found out I am getting Request Timeout even though my internet speed is fast. So I called my ISP and reported the problem, they said they will check the lines and configurations and so on. Now five days have passed and they haven't done a thing. So out of curiosity, I pathping-ed to google to see the where the connections pass through before going through the ISP it showed:

- 0 My PC IP?
- 1 Default gateway (Our own router at home)
- 2 Main Router (since we're sharing with our neighbor)
- 3 ISP

I tried to directly ping these two routers (1 & 2) and found out that only the main router had request timeout which I think causes the lag spike (if not ISP sided). Now I wonder what could be the problem. Anyone pros out there can help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Routers can be configured to not respond to pings (as a security precaution). That's why is use `pathping` which usually goes past the non-responsive router.

Comment: If cabling has been sitting in place for long, try to "rub" them (=pick out, hold locking tab, grind the connector in and out in the mating connector). This may help at least temporary, if this is the problem then additional "electronics `contact cleaner` spray" might be a more lasting remedy.

Comment: What is the connection between 1 and 2 ?